# How to create a gap between some text and an input field for a form?

Tags: html

I want tex on the left, a constant gap between the text and the input field in a form.

I've tried GridLayout and Flexboxes.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <div><a>label 1</a><input /></div>
  <div><a>a longer label here</a><input /></div>
  <div><a>name</a><input /></div>
  <div><a>phone number</a><input /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected result: aligned the input fields with a gap to the labels.
[image]

Comment: You say that you want a "constant gap" but in your drawing the gap is not constant, it changes depending on the length of the text so that the inputs are aligned ... which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You'd basically need to define a standard with for the `<a>` elements.

Also I would recommend to switch to the `label` tag as it's designed for this.

Something like:

```css
div > a {
   width: 150px;
}
```

If you were using a responsive design scheme you could simply handle a specific number of columns for the labels and another specific number for the inputs. That way you'd have a standard structure.

If you are familiar with front end frameworks there are already elements that work like this.

- [Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/forms.html#inline-labels-and-buttons)
- [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/)